# Mysql: "SET @Variable = 0" in one query [Java]

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-variables

I have two sql queries. But in Java I can't set variables.

I tried to summarize it to one query. But that not works, because the sql syntax is wrong.

```
SET @rn = 0;
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT t.id, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rank 
      FROM stats t 
      ORDER BY t.points DESC) t2 
WHERE t2.id = ?;
```

Comment: Are you sending the statements in one batch or splitting the individual statements? If the latter, does the Java library you are using allow sending multiple statements in one query? What exactly makes you think that Java doesn't allow functions or that the SQL syntax is wrong? Does documentation say so? Is it because you're getting an error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If only the SET part is the problem you can do

```
SELECT t.id, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rank 
FROM stats t 
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @rn := 0 ) as parameters
ORDER BY t.points DESC
```

You can also check this tutorial http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a join like this :

```
SELECT stats.id, @rn := @rn+1 AS rank
FROM stats, (SELECT @rn:=0) a
WHERE stats.id = ?
```

If you have mysql 8.0 you can use:  [ROW_NUMBER() or RANK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number)  :

```
SELECT
   id,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER w AS 'row_number',
   RANK()       OVER w AS 'rank',
FROM stats
WHERE stats.id = ?
WINDOW w AS (ORDER BY points);
```